# Is there a confidence score like property in libsvm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am using libsvm python interface and wondering is there a way to get a confidence score/probability when using multi-classification

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend the scikit-learn wrapper of libSVM which incoroporates a predict_proba function and a score function http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.

Comment: This is not an unreasonable answer, as scikit-learn uses libsvm for its own SVM algorithms.

Comment: Was the reasonableness of my answer in question?

Comment: Someone voted you down, so I guess so.